# How to simulate an ftp transfer of a big file with curl?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, libcurl

I want to check the FTP connection with FTP server. To do that I want to make a transfer of big file (like 10 G) to the FTP server (upload) inorder to check my FTP connection.

But to do that I have to generate a big file of 10 G. and this is not good especially if my device does not have enough memory/disk. So I want to simulate a transfer of big file (of 10 G for example) without generating a file of 10G.

Is it possible to do it with curl command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need either 10GB ram or 10GB harddrive space available in order to do that

Comment: If it's possible to specify standard input as the "file" to upload, you can use `dd` to pipe an arbitrary, but specific, amount of data from `/dev/zero` to `curl`. To be clear, this will actually *transfer* 10GB of zeros to the FTP server.

Comment: ARe you simulation upload or download from the device ?

Comment: @chepner could you clarify more with example of commands in an answer.

Comment: If you want to simulate *downloading* a file, you are out of luck; `curl` simply fetches what the remote server gives it. I've never used `curl` for FTP, but something like `dd bs=1 count=10g if=/dev/zero | curl -T- $URL` would upload a 10GB file consisting of zeros.

Comment: @chepner is it possible to generate random content for file with `if=/dev/urandom` instead of zero content

Comment: Yeah, you can read from any file you like. I picked `/dev/zero` rather than trying to decide between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` (I can never remember the difference between them).

Comment: If you're going to use libcurl in software, you can use `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` to write random bytes during the upload, and keep track of how many you've sent and then complete the upload when you've hit your desired file size.

Answer (score 3):

'truncate' (the command line tool) is your friend. It can create *huge* files that are ["sparse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), meaning that the long sequence of zeroes is just a hole that won't actually occupy space on the drive.

Therefore, you can create a 10G file (containing all zeroes) in a much smaller file system and hard drive like this (works on Linux):

```
$ truncate --size=10G bigfile
```

Answer (score 0):

With FTP, assuming that the client and server have small RT delay, sending 10G will take the same amount of sending 100 files of 100M, over the same open connection. Hopefully your device can have that much space allocated.

The key is to avoid re-openning the connection. Do something like the following to keep the connection open.

```
X=ftp://server/path/to/100M
X100=$(for i in {1..100} ; do echo " " $X ; done )
curl $X100
```